# How to edit a message twice in a row?

Tags: c#, .net, discord, console-application, discord.net

I have 3 button in a message when I click on the last one this one modifies the button of the message to deactivate it. then when I click on the first button it no longer works.

```
[ComponentInteraction("close-e:*")]
public async Task HandleCloseButton(ulong id)
{
    var messageComponent = (SocketMessageComponent)Context.Interaction;
    
    await messageComponent.Message.ModifyAsync(x =>
    {
        var comp = ComponentBuilder.FromComponents(messageComponent.Message.Components);
        comp.ActionRows[0].Components.Remove(comp.ActionRows[0].Components.First());

        var newButtons = comp.ActionRows.SelectMany(r => r.Components.OfType<ButtonComponent>())
            .Select(l => l.ToBuilder()).ToList();
        
        newButtons.Insert(0,
            new ButtonBuilder("Close", "test1", ButtonStyle.Danger, emote: new Emoji("\uD83D\uDD12"),
                isDisabled: true));
        
        var test = new ComponentBuilder().WithButton(newButtons[0]).WithButton(newButtons[1])
            .WithButton(newButtons[2]);
        
        x.Components = test.Build();
    });
    await RespondAsync(components: ComponentService.BtnTicketStar(id).Build(), embed: EmbedService.PostReview().Build());
}
```

I would like to know how to modify a message that has already been modified just after and why it does not work?

Comment: Debug your code and look for uncaught exceptions or something. There is nothing that prevents a message from being edited multiple times besides rate limits, and if you are being rate limited, you should get an message stating such.

Comment: no error no exceptions